# Android GCM Message not receiving

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending GCM message from my server with gcm.php. And it says messages sent.

```
{"multicast_id":6717271501903387817,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1459264392497404%479be975f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

For the Android Here is the AndroidManifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="android.jokerslab.com.demogpsinfonet.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.jokerslab.com.demogpsinfonet.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- GCM Permissions - End here  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <!-- android.jokerslab.com.demogpsinfonet-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


<receiver
    android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="GCMNotificationIntentService" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<!-- Register Service -->
<service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
```

BoradCast Receiver :

```
 public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

Notificaiton Service :

```
  public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    public static final int notifyID = 9001;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
  }

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:nn"
                    + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "It's working",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Alert")
            .setContentText("You've received new message.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark);
    // Set pending intent
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    // Set the content for Notification
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("New message from Server");
    // Set autocancel
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    // Post a notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
   }
 }
```

Any Hints what am i missing here ?

Comment: First you have to check API_KEY which is pass in Php api Side..it's use server_key not android_key..Please Mention which one is use in your php code.

Comment: A lot of the code you are using to receive the data in your Android side is deprecated. You might wanna update it for maintainability reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In the manifest file, I think you are missing some lines for the receiver:

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService"
                android:exported="false" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```

If we check the document for Set up a [GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config) and compare to the given manifest code that support GCM, the code above is missing in your manifest file.

> To receive simple downstream messages, use a service that
>    extendsGcmListenerService to handle messages captured by GcmReceiver.
>    GcmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver, guaranteeing that the
>    CPU is awake so that your listener service can complete its task.
>
> By overriding the method GcmListenerService.onMessageReceived, you can
>    perform actions based on the received message:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

register receiver in manifest as

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="packageName" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

and in in GCMIntentService

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {
    // context=GCMIntentService.this;
    this.context=context;
    notifyMessage(data);


}
```